# How do I set my 2nd datepicker one day ahead of the 1st?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 datepicker textfields: one of them is #from, the other is #to.
Right now, my users can have the same date for #from and #to.

How do I make the #to datepicker start at #from + 1 day?

Here's my current code:

```
   var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({   
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to call .datepicker() separately for each textbox and onselect callback set second textbox one day ahead

Comment: Mind showing me how so I can accept  your answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var dates =$( "#from" ).datepicker({   
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings );
        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var toDate = (date.getDate()+1) + '/' + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
       $( "#to").val(toDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't do what I need though, I think you misunderstood the question. Take a look at [this link](http://thestrand.spin-demo.com/). On the left you can see the dates that need to be filled with the date picker (each of them need to be done manually). The thing is I want the starting date - when using the datepicker - to be 1 day later than the date that was picked by the first datepicker.